# Google Actions return Sorry power control is not yet supported

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I implemeneted my device by extending the Assistant as documented in [instructions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/extend/register-device-traits)

I can see my device registered with the traits:

> googlesamples-assistant-devicetool list --model

```
        Device Model Id: assistant-19etc....
        Project Id: assistant-19etc....
        Device Type: action.devices.types.LIGHT
        Trait action.devices.traits.OnOff
        Trait action.devices.traits.StartStop
```

However when I say **Ok Google, turn on**  as mentioned [in here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/extend/handle-device-commands)

I receive the event :

> ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:

with the text

> turn on

but not the action

> ON_DEVICE_ACTION:

Instead the assistant says to me:

> ***Sorry power  control is not yet supported***

Is the Assitent library/service  limited to regions, or is there any other limitation why I do not receive the actions back despite I followed the instructions and according to them all seems to work?

Comment: Can you include the nickname in the query, ie. "Turn on the raspberry pi" (or whatever name it has) and see if it works?

Comment: had the same experience with Assistant on Raspberry PI a few days ago, exactly using `turn on` command. 


    ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
    ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE
    ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
      {'text': 'turn on'}


all seems to be recognized. I have other devices connected to Google Home, but not sure if that is the reason. Looking forward to what others will chime in this thread. Thanks for the post.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue. Well, I have no other device connected. So it seems like a bug or a regional limitation. Are you from Europe?

Comment: @Nick yes I tried both the instruction command : Ok Google, turn on. with the answer : Sorry power control is not yet supported, then also Switch on ,without or  including the device name, Turn on with the device name. In these situations the answer was Sorry, I can,t help with that, or Sorry , I don't understand that, or Sorrry not sure how to help with that....

Comment: Are you using the pushtotalk or hotword sample? Are you making sure to include the device id as a parameter when you start the script?

Answer (score 1):

After playing hours with assistant, and reading the docummenattion over and over, I found out , there is a hidden meaning and missing instructions hidden behind this sentence:

> When you run the sample, it will generate a device instance for your particular device. This device instance will be associated with the device model that you specified to run the sample. Find the device instance ID in the output for the sample. You will use this ID to update your device so you can use Device actions.
>
> device_model_id: my-model device_id: 1C3E1558B0023E49F71CA0D241DA03CF

What the document forgot to mention is that you must not only register the model but you also have to register the device as writen in [reference](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/device-registration/device-tool)

After registering the device with all the needed fields including nick I was able to receive the actions.

And this is exactly where you will need the device id from that sentence above... Somehow this step dropped off from the documantation :-)

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-device [OPTIONS]

  Registers a device instance under an existing device model.

  Device instance fields must start with a letter or number. The device ID
  can only contain letters, numbers, and the following symbols: period (.),
  hyphen (-), underscore (_), and plus (+). The device nickname can only
  contain numbers, letters, and the space ( ) symbol.

Options:
  --device TEXT                   Enter an identifier for a device instance.
                                  If the device ID already exists, this
                                  command will update the device instance. If
                                  it does not exist, this command will create
                                  a new device instance. This ID must be
                                  unique within all of the devices registered
                                  under the same Google Developer project.
                                  [required]
  --model TEXT                    Enter the identifier for an existing device
                                  model. This new device instance will be
                                  associated with this device model.
                                  [required]
  --nickname TEXT                 Enter a nickname for the device. You can use
                                  this name when talking to your Assistant to
                                  refer to this device.
  --client-type [SERVICE|LIBRARY]
                                  Select the type of the client. Use SERVICE
                                  if using the Google Assistant Service or
                                  LIBRARY if using the Google Assistant
                                  Library.  [required]
```

Comment: I have same issue. In the latest versions google assistant SDK googlesamples-assistant-hotword crashes with `Segmentation fault`. Should it be running in order for the device to be visible?