# Trait onoff is not working with Raspberry Pi and google assistant

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I try to setup google Assistant on Raspberry Pi 3B+
on this step [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/handle-device-commands)

this is the onoff-Trait to switch the LED

```
Query: Turn on

INFO:root:Recording audio request.
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "turn".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "turn on".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "turn  on".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "turn on".
INFO:root:End of audio request detected.
INFO:root:Stopping recording.
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "turn on".
INFO:root:Playing assistant response.
INFO:root:Finished playing assistant response.
```

Responses

- Sorry Power controls is not yet supported
- I can not do that yet
- I’m sorry, I don’t quite understand

I found also this topics and tried it:

1. [How do you make your project available so you can use the OnOff trait with google assistant on raspberry pi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60313808/how-do-you-make-your-project-available-so-you-can-use-the-onoff-trait-with-googl)
2. [Google Actions return Sorry power control is not yet supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486092/google-actions-return-sorry-power-control-is-not-yet-supported(but) this is quite old and now only SERVICE and pushtotalk ist available)

I also looked in Troubleshoot: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/troubleshooting#traits

In Troubleshout and 2. Topic is written: you may should register the device manually with this command

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-device [OPTIONS]
```

I tried to do, but no kind of command variation is working.
And also it shows diffrent syntax/Usage on help and on Google Manual
and it seems that the sequence is important

Thank you very much

Comment: hey, I'm having a similar issue, did you find a solution yet? :)

Comment: Hello, No I dit not find a Solution yet. I tried it again after some time and it was working, but I did not change annything. The next time I tried it was not working again! so I think it seams like an internal problem/error in google, I don't know